# Using a for each loop to give multiple pictureboxes a random image VB.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach

Hey guys first of all thanks for your time

I am programming a board game and at one point I need 6 dices.

For 1 dice I did the following code

```
Dim Dobbel as integer
Dim RandomNumber as new Random

Dobbel = RandomNumber.Next(1, 6)

        Select Case Dobbel
            Case 1
                Steen1.Image = Game.My.Resources.Een

            Case 2
                Steen1.Image = Game.My.Resources.Twee

            Case 3
                Steen1.Image = Game.My.Resources.Drie

            Case 4
                Steen1.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vier

            Case 5
                Steen1.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vijf

            Case 6
                Steen1.Image = Game.My.Resources.Zes

        End Select
```

this way it works with 1 dice (the picturebox gets the right picture)

Now I would like 5 more dices to do the above.
I've been trying this with a 'for each' statement but I couldn't get it to work.
Help me plz

P.S. this is my first post ever sorry about things I did wrong

Comment: _"things I did wrong"_ you could tell us what _"i couldn't get it to work"_ means.

Comment: You declared `RandomNumber` variable inside the loop or outside the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "couldn't get it to work" means you didn't know how to loop the six PictureBox controls, try putting them into an array:

```
For Each pb As PictureBox In New PictureBox() {steen1, steen2, steen3, steen4, steen5, steen6}
  Select Case RandomNumber.Next(1, 7)
    Case 1 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Een
    Case 2 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Twee
    Case 3 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Drie
    Case 4 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vier
    Case 5 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vijf
    Case 6 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Zes
  End Select
Next
```

This assumes you have six PictureBoxes named steen#, etc.

Also note that I changed your Random range to 1 - 7.  The max is one less, so in your code, you were never getting a number 6 for an image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Dobbel(6) as integer
Dim RandomNumber as new Random
for (int = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Dobbel(i) = RandomNumber.Next(1, 6)
}

For Each i As Integer In Dobbel
{
        Select Case Dobbel(i)
            Case 1
                Steen(i).Image = Game.My.Resources.Een

            Case 2
                Steen(i).Image = Game.My.Resources.Twee

            Case 3
                Steen(i).Image = Game.My.Resources.Drie

            Case 4
                Steen(i).Image = Game.My.Resources.Vier

            Case 5
                Steen(i).Image = Game.My.Resources.Vijf

            Case 6
                Steen(i).Image = Game.My.Resources.Zes

        End Select
}
```

and of course Steen must be declared as array.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, Although your solution works just fine, I chose the other one because it is more compact and clean.

Thanks!